# Find the product with the worst and best sales by USD for each semester in every year

Tags: mysql

I have the table `sales_by_year_semester` defined as

```sql
CREATE TABLE `sales_by_year_semester` (
    `order_year` INT(4) NOT NULL,
    `semester` TINYINT(1),
    `year_semester` VARCHAR(6),
    `productCode` VARCHAR(10),
    `total_sales_in_usd` FLOAT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

It has the following data:

```
| order_year | semester | year_semester | productCode | total_sales_in_usd |
|------------|----------|---------------|-------------|--------------------|
| 2019       | 1        | 2019-1        | S32_2206    | 2025.16            |
| 2019       | 1        | 2019-1        | S24_2972    | 2285.76            |
| 2019       | 1        | 2019-1        | S18_3232    | 26052.88           |
| 2019       | 2        | 2019-2        | S24_1937    | 6770.34            |
| 2019       | 2        | 2019-2        | S24_2840    | 7159.86            |
| 2019       | 2        | 2019-2        | S12_1099    | 44466.99           |
| 2019       | 2        | 2019-2        | S10_1949    | 48878.16           |
| 2019       | 2        | 2019-2        | S18_3232    | 77427.42           |
| 2020       | 1        | 2020-1        | S24_1937    | 3903.19            |
| 2020       | 1        | 2020-1        | S24_2840    | 4470.39            |
| 2020       | 1        | 2020-1        | S10_4698    | 37297.31           |
| 2020       | 1        | 2020-1        | S12_1108    | 39203.54           |
| 2020       | 1        | 2020-1        | S18_3232    | 43418.87           |
| 2020       | 2        | 2020-2        | S24_3969    | 7907.94            |
| 2020       | 2        | 2020-2        | S24_1937    | 8303.47            |
| 2020       | 2        | 2020-2        | S12_1108    | 66283.92           |
| 2020       | 2        | 2020-2        | S18_3232    | 76962.53           |
| 2021       | 1        | 2021-1        | S24_3969    | 4235.98            |
| 2021       | 1        | 2021-1        | S24_1937    | 5660.64            |
| 2021       | 1        | 2021-1        | S10_4698    | 34856.12           |
| 2021       | 1        | 2021-1        | S18_3232    | 52978.28           |
```

How can I obtain the product with the least/most sales by USD, and it's `productCode` for each `year_semester` in the following format:

```
| order_year | semester | year_semester | productCode_least_sales | least_sales_in_usd | productCode_most_sales | most_sales_in_usd |
|------------|----------|---------------|-------------------------|--------------------|------------------------|-------------------|
| 2019       | 1        | 2019-1        | S32_2206                | 2025.16            | S18_3232               | 26052.88          |
| 2019       | 2        | 2019-2        | S24_1937                | 6770.34            | S18_3232               | 77427.42          |
| 2020       | 1        | 2020-1        | S24_1937                | 3903.19            | S18_3232               | 43418.87          |
| 2020       | 2        | 2020-2        | S24_3969                | 7907.94            | S18_3232               | 76962.53          |
| 2021       | 1        | 2021-1        | S24_3969                | 4235.98            | S18_3232               | 52978.28          |
```

What I tried to do was use a `CASE WHEN` to select the `MIN(total_sales_in_usd)`, `MAX(total_sales_in_usd)` but I cannot obtain the corresponding `productCode` for each value.

```sql
SELECT 
    order_year,
    semester,
    year_semester, 
    CASE WHEN 
        MIN(DISTINCT total_sales_in_usd) THEN productCode END 
        as productCode_least_sales,
    MIN(total_sales_in_usd),
    CASE WHEN 
        MAX(DISTINCT total_sales_in_usd) THEN productCode END as productCode_most_sales,
    MAX(total_sales_in_usd)
    FROM
        sales_by_year_semester 
    GROUP BY 
        year_semester ;
```

Comment: I guess I'm confused. Do you want, for each product, to figure out the `MAX` and `MIN` sale? Do you want to know which product had the `MAX` and which had the `MIN`? Do you want to know which products accounted for the most total sales and the least total sales? Is this in USD or in frequencies?

Comment: I need to find the `productCode` with the least sales and the most sales for each `year_semester`

Comment: by count or USD?

Comment: by `total_sales_in_usd`

Comment: Incidentally, money is almost never FLOAT; it's why DECIMAL was invented!

Answer (score 0):

you can do `left join` instead.

```
select t1.*, minProduct.product_code,  t2.minSales, maxProduct.product_code, t3.maxSales from 
    (select distinct order_year
        , semester
        , year_semester
    from sales_by_year_semester) as t1
left join
    (select  order_year
        , min(total_sales_in_usd) as minSales   
    from sales_by_year_semester group by order_year) as t2 on t2.order_year = t1.order_year
left join
    (select order_year
        , max(total_sales_in_usd) as maxSales       
    from sales_by_year_semester group by order_year, ) as t3 on t3.order_year = t1.order_year
left join
    (select product_code, total_sales_in_usd, order_year
        from sales_by_year_semester) as minProduct 
            on minProduct.total_sales_in_usd = t2.minSales and minProduct.order_year=t2.order_year
left join
    (select product_code, total_sales_in_usd, order_year
        from sales_by_year_semester) as maxProduct
            on maxProduct.total_sales_in_usd = t3.maxSales and maxProduct.order_year=t2.order_year
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using `ROW_NUMBER` for this type of problem.  Assuming you are using MySQL 8+, we can try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year_semester ORDER BY total_sales_in_usd) rn_min,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year_semester ORDER BY total_sales_in_usd DESC) rn_max
    FROM sales_by_year_semester
)

SELECT
    order_year,
    semester,
    year_semester,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_min = 1 THEN productCode END) AS productCode_least_sales,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_min = 1 THEN total_sales_in_usd END) AS least_sales_in_usd,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_max = 1 THEN productCode END) AS productCode_most_sales,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_max = 1 THEN total_sales_in_usd END) AS most_sales_in_usd
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    order_year,
    semester,
    year_semester
ORDER BY
    order_year,
    semester,
    year_semester;
```